# Passing value from javascript to PHP ( Using Hidden Field )

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, validation

After doing some googling, I still get confused...
I'm trying to pass the counted radio button value (Javascript) to PHP through hidden field that later on will be inserted to database MySQL.
I have a form named test.html

```
<html>
<head><script type="text/javascript" src="../js/script.js"></script</head>
<body>
<form name="myform" method="post"
 onSubmit="return validateRadio()" action="">

<table class="tftable" border="1">
<tr><th><div align="center" class="tftable th">Questions</div></th><th colspan="2"><div align="center">Answer</div></th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>I like to dance</td>
  <td>
  <label></label>
  <label>
  <input name="bm1" type="radio" value="1" />
  Yes</label>
</td>
<td>
<label></label>
<label>
<input name="bm1" type="radio" value="2" />
No
</label>
</td></table>
<input type="hidden" name="passvalue" id="passvalue" value="">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's script.js that counted the radio button... The value that I want to pass is answeramount value

```
function validateRadio()
{
// get all the inputs type
var inputs = myform.elements;
var radios = [];

// find the radio type
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i) {
if (inputs[i].type == 'radio') {
radios.push(inputs[i]);
}
}
var countChecked = 0;
for (var j = 0; j < radios.length; j++) {
if (radios[j].checked) {
countChecked++;
}
}
//count number of radio button with value=1
var answeramount = 0;
for (var k = 0; k < radios.length; k++){
if(radios[k].checked && radios[k].value==1){
answeramount++;
}
}
if (countChecked != radios.length / 2){
alert("All questions must be answered.");
return false; // abort submit
} else {
alert("All questions have been answered.");
return true; // proceed to submit
} 
}
```

Please show me how to pass "answeramount" value to php that later on will be inserted to database. Thanks

EDIT:

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aG64e/1/)

Comment: change `önSubmit` to `onSubmit`

Answer (score 0):

You can use that simple code to manipulate a input's value:

```
var field = document.getElementById('#passvalue');
field.value = answeramount;
```

Place this snipped right between your counting and the alert,

The php side would be a standard POST to sql script (there are several tutorials out there)
Your hidden input would be $_POST['passvalue']

Comment: Why use jQuery for a simple task? Guns and sparrows!

Comment: I'm pretty new to Javascript and jQuery. Where should i place the jQuery? @hauke

Comment: You are right, jQuery is not nessesary here. I edited my post. (Also with instructions where to put this)

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="passvalue" id="passvalue" value="<?php echo $passvalue; ?>"> is it right? @Hauke

Answer (score 0):

correct your HTML: read the comments!

and in your function add

```
...
else {
    alert("All questions have been answered.");
    document.getElementById("passvalue").value = answeramount;
    return true; // proceed to submit
}
...
```

In PHP you can get the value from **$_POST[ 'passvalue' ]**.

```
<?php
$passvalue = ( isset( $_POST[ 'passvalue' ] ) ? (int)$_POST[ 'passvalue' ] : 0  );
?>
```

update:
better readable code:

```
<?php
// check: if the index "passavlue" is set
// equivalent to ternary operator [ expression ? <give true> : <give false> ] 
if( isset( $_POST[ 'passvalue' ] ) ){
    // cast the string to integer
    $passvalue = (int) $_POST[ 'passvalue' ];
}
else{
    $passvalue = 0;
}
?>
```

Comment: At the hidden field value:
<input type="hidden" name="passvalue" id="passvalue" value="<?php echo $passvalue; ?>"> is it right? @raiserle

Comment: by `<input type="hidden" name="passvalue" id="passvalue" value="<?php echo $passvalue; ?>">` you have the PHP-Value in your form

Comment: I really apreciate your help. I have updated the code... Actually I will create another php file(which include your php code) to catch the value... Please take a look if the code is right except for the PHP position. http://jsfiddle.net/6D3fG/1/ @raiserle

Answer (score 0):

$passvalue=isset($_POST['passvalue'])?$_POST['passvalue']:"";

The passvalue field should

input type="hidden" name="passvalue" id="passvalue" value=" echo  $passvalue; "

And at the javascript

alert("All questions have been answered.");
document.getElementsById('passvalue').Value = answeramount;

Comment: What do you mean?  **">**

Comment: $passvalue=isset($_POST['passvalue'])?$_POST['passvalue']:"";
Isn't just the same like $passvalue=isset($_POST['passvalue'])  ?